# Who narrated each of the major 18 Puranas?

Tags: puranas

**NOTE:** This question is **NOT** a duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/who-wrote-or-composed-put-together-the-puranas) question. I am not asking who *composed* the Puranas, but rather who *narrated* them.

Many of the Puranas were narrated by [Suta Goswami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugrashravas) to a group of Rishis headed by [Saunaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaunaka).

The *[Srimad Bhagavata Purana](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/1/)* was narrated by him:

> Text 4: Once, in a holy place in the forest of Naimiṣāraṇya, great
>   sages headed by the sage Śaunaka assembled to perform a great
>   thousand-year sacrifice for the satisfaction of the Lord and His
>   devotees.
>
> Text 5: One day, after finishing their morning duties by burning a
>   sacrificial fire and offering a seat of esteem to Śrīla Sūta Gosvāmī,
>   the great sages made inquiries, with great respect, about the
>   following matters.

The *[Garuda Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu03.htm)* was narrated by him:

> 2. In Naimiṣa, the field of the sleepless Ones, the sages, Saunaka and others, performed sacrifices for thousands of years to attain the
>      Heaven-world.
>
> 3-5. Those sages once, in the morning, having offered oblations to the
>   sacrificial fire respectfully asked this of the revered Sūta sitting
>   there:

Wikipedia says Suta also narrated the Padma Purana.

Who narrated each of the major 18 Puranas?

Please answer with a list of each Purana and who narrated it, along with the initial verses proving the narrator.