# Who divided Vedas?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, vyasa

According to the Vishnu Purana the original Veda was divided into four parts, and further fragmented into numerous shakhas, by Vishnu in the form of Vyasa, in the  Dvapara Yuga; the Vayu Purana recounts a similar division by Vyasa, at the urging of Brahma. The Bhagavata Purana traces the origin of the primeval Veda to the syllable aum, and says that it was divided into four at the start of Dvapara Yuga, because men had declined in age, virtue and understanding.

However, if we consider the order of evolution of Vedas, Mahabharata, Srimad Ramayana, etc, we can understand that Vedas were followed by Srimad Ramayana.  And, after a long period Mahabharata came into existence.

So if we go by these stories, the Vedas should have been remained undivided in the Ramayana era.  If we read Srimad Ramayana carefully, we will find that Vedas were already divided into 3 parts by the time  Sri Rama came into existence.

---

1. ```
     Sri Hanuma approaches, at the behest of Sugreeva, Sri Rama and Lakshmana to  know the intentions of those two by their conduct, by their semblance, and by their conversation.  

      After listening to him, Sri Rama expresses his opinion on Sri Hanuma to Lakshmana as follows:
   ```

न अन् ऋग्वेद विनीतस्य न अ--यजुर्वेद धारिणः |
न अ--साम वेद विदुषः शक्यम् एवम् विभाषितुम् ||

(Kishkinda Kanda 3rd Sarga 28th Sloka)

"Nay...the non-knower of Rig Veda, or the non-rememberer of Yajur Veda, or the non-scholar of Saama Veda... can possibly, or truly speak this way..."

Here, Sri Rama was saying that Sri Hanuma was well versed in Rig, Yajur, Saama Vedas.  So by that time Vedas might have already been divided into 3 parts only but not 4 parts.

2. While describing the characteristics and bodily signs of Sri Rama to Sita, Sri Hanuma says as follows:

यजुः वेद विनीतः च वेदविद्भिः सुपूजितः |
धनुः वेदे च वेदे च वेद अन्गेषु च निष्ठितः ||  (Sundara Kanda 35th Sarga 14th Sloka)

"He got trained in Yajurveda, the sacrificial Veda. He is highly honoured by those well-versed in Vedas. He is skilled in Dhanurveda, the science of archery, other Vedas and the six limbs of Vedangas."

Sri Rama was trained in Yajurveda.  So Vedas were divided in Srimad Ramayana era itself.

Then why this division of Vedas was attributed to **Sage Vyasa**?

Comment: Do you want a mythological answer as the one currently posted or a historical one? If latter, suggest you remove the 'mythology' tag from the question and instead add the 'history' tag.

Comment: I have deleted the Mythology tag.  @sv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Veda was available only 3 parts, ie., Rig, Sama and Yajur at the time of composition of Ramayana by Sage Valmiki.  That was why Sage Valmiki mentioned it so.

A mention as made in the 2nd sloka of 15th Sarga of Bala Kanda about atharvashIrsha - **अथर्वशिरसि**.

> इष्टिं तेऽहं करिष्यामि पुत्रीयां पुत्रकारणात् | **अथर्वशिरसि**
> प्रोक्तैर्मन्त्रैः सिद्धां विधानतः || १-१५-२
>
> "I will procedurally conduct the ritual contained in the preamble of
> ***atharva-veda*** with procedural hymns, called <*>putra kaameSTi i.e.,
> the ritual that bestows sons, for your benefit."*

However, as this sloka was mentioned as a preamble to [putrakAmeshthi yagna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/41217/3869), which is an interpolated story in Ramayana, this sloka is also an interpolated one.

Thus, by the time Ramayana was composed, there were only 3 Vedas.

---

If we go through the [Manu Smriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199771.html), we can find that it mentions about 3 Vedas only.

> षट् त्रिंशदाब्दिकं चर्यं गुरौ **त्रैवेदिकं** व्रतम् । तदर्धिकं पादिकं वा
> ग्रहणान्तिकमेव वा ॥ १ ॥
>
> ṣaṭ triṃśadābdikaṃ caryaṃ gurau traivedikaṃ vratam | tadardhikaṃ
> pādikaṃ vā grahaṇāntikameva vā || 1 ||
>
> Duties relating to the ***Three Vedas*** should be observed under the
> Preceptor for thirty-six years, or for half that period, or for a
> quarter, or precisely till they have been got up.

---

Let us consider what text from other way of faith Buddhism say about the number of Vedas.

The [Sutta Nipāta 1026 (P.303)](http://ftp.budaedu.org/ebooks/pdf/EN391.pdf) mentions about 3 vedas only.

> His age is a hundred and twenty years, by clan he is a Bāvarī, upon
> his body appear three signs, ***Three Vedas*** he has mastered all.

We should remember that that Gautama, the Buddha took birth in a Hindu family only. He studied the prevalent literature , observed the prevalent customs and practices , got vexed with the degraded form of spiritual aspects in his times, adopted his own method and finally reached the stage SAT, which Veda described in ***RV 1.164.46***.

---

Bhagavad Gita ***is a part of Mahabharata***.  While explaining the various aspects, Sri Krishna says in the "Rajavidya Rajaguhya Yoga" as follows:

> पिताऽहमस्य जगतो माता धाता पितामहः। वेद्यं पवित्रमोंकार ***ऋक् साम
> यजुरेव*** च।।9.17।।
>
> I am both the father and the mother of the universe, I am the
> Maintainer, the Grandsire, the object of all knowledge, the purifier,
> the syllable oµ and I am the Rig Veda, ***Såma Veda and the Yajur
> Veda***.

Srimad Bhagavad Gita was narrated to Arjuna by Sri Krishna, almost at the end of Dwapar Yuga.  Even at time also, the vedas ***were 3 parts only***, but not 4.

The **Atharvana Veda** is missing.

---

Now, coming to the question part - Who divided the Vedas?, we have to take a holistic look to understand the issue.

1. The **Rig Veda**, composed by various sages at different times, was/is/will be the source of Dharma, for attaining SPIRITUAL heights, for talking anything about Sanatana Dharma.
2. ***[Sama is Rasa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23511/3869)*** or essence of Rig-Veda i.e. That is most essential part.
3. The Yagnas mentioned in Rig Veda are mostly mind related, but misunderstood by many and interpreted them to be physical.  That is why the **Yajur Veda** contains physical yagnas.

Even in Ramayana, we can find the importance of Yajur Veda.  Sri Rama was described as यजुः वेद विनीतः -  trained in Yajurveda.

> यजुः वेद विनीतः च वेदविद्भिः सुपूजितः | धनुः वेदे च वेदे च वेद अन्गेषु
> च निष्ठितः || ५-३५-१४
>
> "He got trained in Yajurveda, the sacrificial Veda. He is highly
> honoured by those well-versed in Vedas. He is skilled in Dhanurveda,
> the science of archery, other Vedas and the six limbs* of Vedangas."

---

No body divided Vedas into parts.  The Sama and Yajur vedas evolved from Rig Veda.

[Sama Veda](https://vedicfeed.com/the-four-vedas/)

> The Sama Veda, divided into two major parts, first to include the four
> melody collections, or the Saman, the songs and the latter the Arcika,
> or the verse books a collection (Samhita) of hymns, portions of hymns,
> and detached verses. A liturgical text, relating to public worship,
> ***all but 75 verses of the total 1875 is derived from the Rig Veda.***

[Yajur Veda:](https://vedicfeed.com/the-four-vedas/)

> The earliest and most ancient layer of Yajur Veda, **Samhita includes
> about 1,875 verses, that are distinct yet borrowed from and built upon
> the foundation of verses in Rigveda.**

> The middle layer includes the
> Satapatha Brahmana, one of the largest Brahmana texts in the Vedic
> collection and The youngest layer of Yajur Veda text includes the
> largest collection of primary Upanishads six in number, influential to
> various schools of Hindu philosophy. These include the Brihadaranyaka
> Upanishad, the Isha Upanishad, the Taittiriya Upanishad, just to name
> a few.

### For example: The Purusha Suktam appears both in [Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10090.htm) and [Shukla Yajurveda](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/puruShasUktashuklayajurvedIya.html)

Now the question of attributing the division of the Vedas to Sage Vyasa crops up.

This was attributed by subsequent writers to Sage Vyasa, narrating him to be an [incarnation of Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasa#Early_life).  Attributing authorship of Puranas might have been done by subsequent writers, in order to give authority to Puranas on par with the Vedas.

Comment: 'No body divided Vedas into parts. The Sama and Yajur vedas evolved from Rig Veda.' - can you add a reference for this claim?

Comment: I have updated my answer please @sv.

Comment: So was there a time when only Rigvedic hymns were used to conduct sacrifices? When were the roles hotṛ, adhvaryu, udgātṛ, etc. created? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_priesthood#Chief_priests) after the division of Vedas or before?

Comment: Rig Vedic hymns, indicating Yagnas,  are esoteric in sense.  As far as I understood, the subsequent generations could not grasp the esoteric meaning of Rig Vedic Hymns and evolved physical Yagnas.  During that point of time all these physical posts might have been evolved. @sv.

Answer (score 7):

**It's because there is more than one Vyasa.**  Most people only know "Vyasa" as the name of the sage Krishnadvaipayana Vedavyasa, the son of Parashara and Satyavati who, in the most recent Dwapara Yuga, compiled and divided the body of the Vedic mantras into the four books we call the Vedic Samhitas.  (Technically he only compiled the first Rig, Yajur, and Sama Veda; the Atharvana Veda was an independent effort by the sages Atharva and Angiras.)  But as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3618/36), he is not the only one who has done this.

Vyasa is actually a title, and in each Dwapara Yuga a new Vyasa does the job of compiling and dividing the Vedas.  In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin//vp/vp077.htm) of the Vishnu Purana, the current Vyasa's father Parashara lists the previous Vyasas of the Vaivasvata Manvantara:

> Twenty-eight times have the Vedas been arranged by the great Rishis in the Vaivaswata Manwantara in the Dwápara age, and consequently eight and twenty Vyásas have passed away; by whom, in their respective periods, the Veda has been divided into four. In the first Dwápara age the distribution was made by Swayambhu (Brahmá) himself; in the second, the arranger of the Veda (Veda-vyása) was Prajápati (or Manu); in the third, Uśanas; in the fourth, Vrihaspati; in the fifth, Savitri; in the sixth, Mrityu (Death, or Yama); in the seventh, Indra; in the eighth, Vaśisht́ha; in the ninth, Sáraswata; in the tenth, Tridháman; in the eleventh, Trivrishan; in the twelfth, Bharadwája; in the thirteenth, Antaríksha; in the fourteenth, Vapra; in the fifteenth, Trayyáruńa; in the sixteenth, Dhananjaya; in the seventeenth, Kritanjaya; in the eighteenth, Rińa; in the nineteenth, Bharadwája; in the twentieth, Gotama; in the twenty-first, Uttama, also called Haryátmá; in the twenty-second, Veńa, who is likewise named Rájaśravas; in the twenty-third, Somaśushmápańa, also Trińavindu; **in the twenty-fourth, Riksha, the descendant of Bhrigu, who is known also by the name Válmíki**; in the twenty-fifth, my father Śakti was the Vyása; I was the Vyása of the twenty-sixth Dwápara, and was succeeded by Jaratkáru; the Vyása of the twenty-eighth, who followed him, was Krishńa Dwaipáyana. These are the twenty-eight elder Vyásas, by whom, in the preceding Dwápara ages, the Veda has been divided into four. In the next Dwápara, Drauńi (the son of Drońa) will be the Vyása, when my son, the Muni Krishńa Dwaipáyana, who is the actual Vyása, shall cease to be (in that character).

Now the Vyasa of the twenty-fourth Dwapara Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara was the sage Valmiki, the author of the Ramayana.  The reason I single him out is that Rama was born in the twenty-fourth Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, as I discuss in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/36).  The Ramayana took place in the transition between the Treta Yuga and the Dwapara Yuga of that Mahayuga.

So to sum up, it is the sage Valmiki's edition of the Vedas, not Krishnadwaipayana Veda Vyasa's division, that Rama and Hanuman are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated reply.  If the source the above reply is Puranas or Srimad Bhagavatam, then I am sorry.  After going through the Puranas I found that there are many fabricated stories.  Even in Srimad Ramayana, there was mention about "Krita yuge" - Sundara Kanda - meaning completed/earlier period, but no mention was available about the different Vyasas.  I want a irrefutable reference please.  Once again I repeat I cannot accept quoting from Puranas please

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Well, the thing is that detailed accounts of what events happened in what Yuga and Manvantara are what Puranas or histories are for.  Now I could easily give you quotes from the Mahabharata which say that Parashara's son Vyasa compiled the Vedas.  And I could give you a Mahabharata quote that talks about Ashwatthama's plans to study under the current Vyasa, which is how he'll become the next Vyasa.  But for lists of previous Vyasas we have to turn to the Puranas, just as we have to turn to the Puranas for lists of previous Indras.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv By the way, I suggest you register an account on the site; otherwise you may not be able to edit your questions and answers later on.  You don't even need to choose a password - you can just sign using your Google account.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Also, I think you're taking the wrong attitude to the Puranas.  It's true that they have some interpolated passages, but you should accept a passage from the Puranas as genuine unless you find good reason to believe that it's not authentic, for instance anachronistic style of language and the like.

Comment: I am not taking wrong attitude towards Puranas.  Ever since I was 12 years of age I have been reading Puranas. As far as Mahabharata is concerned, the original version contains 8,800 slokas only. The present version of 1,00,000 slokas Mahabharata may contain what you quoted about Vyasa.  Any way I expressed my opinion, which was formed after a deep thinking only.  It is upto the reader whether to accept it or not

Comment: I tried to register but some how after clicking on the URL provided in my registered mail, it did not go back properly.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The 8800 verses are known as the Jaya, and they constitute the dialogue between Sanjaya and Dhritarashtra.  Then Vyasa composed the 100,000 verse Mahabharata to provide the larger context for the Jaya.  In any case, like I said I fully agree with you that the Puranas have some interpolations.  But we should take a passage from the Puranas as Sabda Pramana until we have good reason to doubt that particular passage.  In any case, do you want me to give you the Mahabharata quotes I was referring to?

Comment: Please do give.   Let me update my knowledge

Comment: OK chapter 60 of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata says "And the illustrious one developed by his will alone his body as soon as he was born, and mastered the Vedas with their branches, and all the histories. And he readily obtained that which no one could obtain by asceticism, by the study of the Vedas, by vows, by fasts, by progeny, and by sacrifice. And the first of Veda-knowing ones, he divided the Vedas into four parts." And Adi Parva chapter 105 says "That illustrious Rishi having by his ascetic power divided the Vedas into four parts hath come to be called on earth by the name of Vyasa"

Comment: Before you quote further, let me pose a question to you.  How can we decide that this portions on Sage Vyasa were not PRAKSHIPTA, an insertions made at a latter date?  which portion contain 8,800 slokas?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The 8800 verses of the Jaya begin in the Bhishma Parva and end in the Sauptika Parva - they constitute Sanjaya's narration to Dhritarashtra based on the divine vision he was given by Vyasa. The rest of the Mahabharata is based on Vyasa's own divine vision. Now as to whether it's possible that the quotes I gave could be later insertions into the text, it's possible that all of Hindu scripture is just later insertions!  But when examining our sacred scriptures, the best approach to take is "innocent until proven guilty" - assume it's authentic until you have reason to doubt it.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv When it comes to the Mahabharata, there were more interpolators later on compared to earlier, and at a fairly early stage the recensions of the Mahabharata split off.  So an easy way to find if a Mahabharata passage is an interpolation or not is to see if it's found in the manuscripts for all the recensions or just for some of them.  Those quotes I gave appear in all the manuscripts, so the probability that they were a later insertion is fairly low.  By the way, I got your account issues resolved - you now have a registered account on the site.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I just found a quote in chapter 350 of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata that discusses previous Vyasas: "the Rishi Apantaratamas ... in the Kalpa named after the Self-born Manu, distributed and arranged the Vedas."  It also says that there will be future Vyasas in other Manvantaras who will arrange the Vedas, and it names Parashara's son Krishnadwaipayana Vedavyasa as one of them.

Comment: If JAYA begins with Bhisma Parva only and ends with Sauptika parva, then  it narrates only war episodes. why should Vyasa bring out a story on War episodes only?  What purpose does it serve unless the earlier story was not told?  Again, if Santiparva was not included in JAYA, then the VISHNU SAHASRANAMA STOTRAM becomes a PRAKSHIPTA

Comment: My opinion is Sage Vyasa wrote JAYA, comprising 8,800 slokas, narrating the story of PANDAVAS and KAURAVAS in brief.  His disciples like Vaisampayana might have elaborated into 22,000 slokas story called BHARATA.  The scholars, who wrote Puranas, might have expanded it to 1,00,000 slokas duly including visiting of Pilgrimages by Pandavas, Vishnu Sahasranama, etc.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Vyasa did not "bring out" the 8800 verses of the Jaya.  The Jaya is just Sanjaya's narration of the war to Dhritarashtra, it's not meant to be a free-standing work.  Vyasa used Sanjaya's account of the war as a starting point for a 24,000-verse poem about the life stories of the Pandavas and Kauravas, called the Bharata.  Then to provide additional context, he composed a larger poem called the Mahabharata by adding Upakhyanas or episodes unconnected to the Pandavas and Kauravas. The Yudhishthira-Bhishma dialogues are not part of an Upakhyana, so they were part of the Bharata.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv So there's absolutely no reason to doubt the Shanti Parva and Anushasana Parva. In any case, if you believe in the numbers 8800, 24000, and 100,000, then you have to believe in the first chapter of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata, which says that the 100,000 verses were composed by Vyasa.  (In fact Vyasa composed 600,000 verses and only taught 100,000 to Vaishampayana.) If you don't accept the first chapter of the Adi Parva, then you have absolutely no basis for believing in a 8800-24000-100,000 division of the Mahabharata.

Comment: Where was it mentioned that 8,800 slokas narration was of Sanjaya's?  Can you quote authority please?

Comment: I am not interested in hurting anyone's feeling.  If my opinions hurt you, I will stop here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29975/discussion-between-keshav-srinivasan-and-srimannarayana-k-v).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan did ganesh wrote 600000 verse or 100000 verse as you said  vyasa composed 600000 verse .