# Was Valmiki (writer of Ramayana) 24th Vyasa?

Tags: ramayana, rama, vyasa, valmiki

**Vishnu Purana**:

[image]

*English Translation:* ([Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm))

> In the twenty-fourth, Riksha (also can be written as Riksh or  Ruksh or Ruksha), the descendant of Bhrigu, who is known also by the name Válmíki

**Kurma Purana:**

[image]

*English Translation:* ([Source](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/veda_vyasa.html))

> Thereafter 24th Vyasa was Valmiki.

Now my questions are as below:

**1. Was this same Valmiki who wrote Ramayana?**

**2. Does 24th Vyasa means Vyasa from 24th Maha Yuga?**

**3. If answer of above two questions are Yes then is it true that there is no Kalpa Bheda in Rama's story from Vayu Purana and Rama incarnation happened in 24th Maha Yuga of current Kalpa->Manvanatra?**

[image]

**4. Does that also mean that Rama incarnation didn't happen again in 28th Maha Yuga as Vayu Purna mention next incarnations as Krishna Dvaipāyana?**

[image]

Comment: Your question already answered here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/who-all-were-the-different-ved-vyas

Comment: Answer for your 2nd question  is yes.

Comment: @CR241 no my question is nowhere duplicate of that question..i hv already went through that question and the source too which is used to answer that question..same source i have used in my question here..i know the list of 28 Vyasas..my question is for clarification on 24th Vyasa only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are good questions. 
1. It seems so that Valmiki being mentioned is the one who wrote Ramayana because we know that Lord Rama came in the the 24th Maha Yuga. 
[See the answer here for Maha yuga details of the avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar)

2. Yes. Vishnu Purana, Linga Purana (chapter 24) etc. mention names of Vyasa incarnations of different Maha yuga. There is Vyasa in every Dwapara yuga.
3. Yes. No Kalpa bheda.
4. Yes. Lord Rama came in the 24th divya/maha yuga. [Reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar)

Comment: For #3, you can have Kalpa bheda and yet have the avatars takin place in 24th Mahayuga of the 6th Manvantara