# What's the story of Bhasmasura in which Lord Vishnu came as a Brahmin and Mohini?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, avatars

I came across two different avatars of Vishnu for killing Bhasmasura while reading about Lord Shiva and lord Vishnu. In one tale Vishnu came as Brahmin to deceive Bhasmasura and in another he came as Mohini. Now can you clear my doubt with a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One version of the story can be found in [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.88](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/88),

> The Supreme Lord, who relieves His devotees’ distress, had seen from afar that Lord Śiva was in danger. Thus by His mystic Yoga-māyā potency He assumed the form of a brahmacārī student, with the appropriate belt, deerskin, rod and prayer beads, and came before Vṛkāsura. The Lord’s effulgence glowed brilliantly like fire. Holding kuśa grass in His hand, He humbly greeted the demon.

Comment: Then what about Mohini avatar?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS It's a partial answer..

Comment: Just now found. Mohini avatar is in Shiva purana. Does this Vrkasura-Shiva-Vishnu is cyclic then?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS May be Yes.... Kalpa Bheda might be in the story and both version might be from different kalpa/cycle... See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21446/12304

Comment: now sorry for this question. Does Kalpa means different Manvantra or the Kalpa after Brahma's 1 day/night?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Kalpa = 14 Manvantras = 1 day of Brahma...

Comment: So which means even Ramayana will happen only in next day of Brahma as current Ramayana already happened in 24th Mahayuga?Sorry for some off topic question !

Comment: That's quite unclear yet..Same is my Question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22939/12304 too...It seems some incidents may repeat in Mahayuga, Manvantra too..in Kalpa, most of the stories gets repeated...