# When did Ved Vyas write Mahabharata and Puranas?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

When Ved Vyas authored Mahabharata and Puranas ? Ved Vyas is Cheeranji and still alive.

When did he write these books ? According to modern Historians , Mahabharata was authored in around 400 BC.
Is it correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who all were the different Ved-Vyas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/who-all-were-the-different-ved-vyas)

Comment: You are asking for opinions as there is no definitive date that has been agreed upon.