# English translation of Karnata Bharata Kathamanjari (Kumara Vyasa Mahabharatha)

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

[Karnata Bharata Kathamanjari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnata_Bharata_Kathamanjari), Kannada version of Mahabharatha written by [Kumara Vyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumara_Vyasa), is said to exact version of Mahabharatha.This kannada version consists story of [Aswathama.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashwatthama#Alternate_theories_about_Ashwatthama.27s_fate) after Krishna's curse. Wikipedia states,

> In a Kannada version of Mahabaratha written by Kumara Vyasa, the author claimed that he wrote Mahabaratha by listening to **Sage Aswatthama**. It was said in different sources and alternate theories that, in order to escape from the curse of Lord Krishna, Aswatthama approached his Parama Guru (guru's guru) Lord Parasurama, who was also an avatar of Lord Vishnu. Lord Parasurama felt pity at Aswatthama and agreed to help him. It was said that Aswatthama was only an instrument in Lord Shiva's plan to exterminate all the evil people from earth. Since it was Lord Shiva who entered into Aswatthama's body and exterminated Pandava forces, Aswatthama was absolved of all sins. It was said that Pandavas met Aswathama once again 36 years later when they were travelling to the Himalayas to seek pardon from Lord Siva for their heinous crimes in war. The description says Pandavas found Aswatthama happy in the company of Lord Parasurama and Sage Durvasa in an ashram on the banks of river Ganga and Aswatthama was found free from all curses. It was believed that Lord Parasurama and Maharishi Durvasa initiated Aswatthama into Sakthi worship, which is considered to be the supreme of all modes of worship. By worshiping Adi ParaSakthi, the mother of Lord Brahma,Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva, Aswatthama bypassed the curse of Lord Krishna

Wiki cited [Kannada Version](https://archive.org/details/KumaraVyasaKarnatnatakaMahabharata)  as reference. I want to read Aswathama chapter in that book.

Where can i get english translation of that kannada Mahabharatha or just *Aswathama episode* of that book?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is just one English translation (an abridged one) of the Kumaravyasa Bharata done by D. Sheshagiri Rao.  The translation is reads rather strained and lacks fluency.

A team of translators, including myself, is currently working on a project of translating significant parts of the Kumaravyasa Bharata to be published in 3 volumes, under the Murty Classical Library of India series, by the Harvard University Press.