# Where is Vālmīki right now?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, history, valmiki

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16757/2995) answer claims that, Vālmīki, the author of Rāmāyaṇa, is still alive:

> **Valmiki is still living.** He was also present during the conversation between Yudhishthira and Bhishma which is recorded in Anushasana Parva of Mahabharata.

If Vālmīki's alive, I wish to know where is he right now. I mean where is he physically present?

If he wasn't alive at the time of Mahābhārata, is it possible that the Mahābhārata is talking about a different Vālmīki or are [those lines](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm) from Anuṣāsana-parva of Mahābhārata a later interpolation (i.e., not part of the original text)?

Comment: Why do you think Valmiki should have died? Sages only leave their body rarely... oldest of the sages Nara-Narayana are still living, Yajnavalkya is living, Vasistha is living, Sahadeva met Vibhisana, Jambawanta met Krishna, Parashara is living... Dadhichi gave up his body so that his bones can be made Vajra.. Suka gave up his body while attaining Moksha .. There are only few rare cases seen where sages gave up their body...

Comment: @Tezz I think vasishtha was killed by vishvamitra through some demon.

Comment: @Tezz [Let's discuss in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51920/where-is-valmiki-right-now).

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande No, Vasistha's sons were killed by Vishwamitra through the demon Kalmashapada, not Vasishtha himself.