# Apart from the Bhavishya Purana, are there any Puranas that talk about Sage Tulsidas?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, smriti, valmiki, ramcharitmanas

According to the  Bhavishya Purana, Lord Shiva tells his wife Parvati how Valmiki got a boon from Hanuman to sing the glory of Rama in vernacular language (i.e. Ramcharitmanas) to incarnate in future in the Kali Yuga as Sage Tulsidas:

> वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
> रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥ (Bhavishya Purana, Pratisarga Parva, 4.20.)

> **Transliteration**: vālmīkistulasīdāsaḥ kalau devi bhaviṣyati ।
> rāmacandrakathāmetāṃ bhāṣābaddhāṃ kariṣyati ॥

> **Translation**: O Goddess [Parvati]! Valmiki will become Tulsidas in the Kali age, and will compose this narrative of Rama in the vernacular language. (Bhavishya Purana, Pratisarga Parva, 4.20.)

Are there any other Puranas that talk about Sage Tulsidas apart from the Bhavishya Purana?

Comment: [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16432/what-happened-to-valmiki-after-the-ramayana-ended/16757#16757) answer claims that Valmiki is still living. He was still living at the time of Mahabharata. So, death of Valmiki is not mentioned in any Puranas AFAIK,

Answer (score 3):

There are many scriptures that show that goswami Tulsidas was actually incarnation of Valmiki.:

> *वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
> रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥*
>
> ***(Bhavishya Purana Pratisarga 4.20).***

**Translation.:**

> ***In the Bhavishyottar Purana, after telling the entire story of Sri Rama, Lord Bhutabhavan Shankara says to Goddess Parvati – “O Parvati!  Maharishi Valmiki will become Tulsidas in Kali Yuga and will translate this Rama Katha into Awadhi language.”***

And the same is supported by other scriptures whose evidence is as follows:~

**Vasishta Samhitayam (quoted from the Triple Principle of Worship, page. 55).:**

> *वाल्मीकितुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
> रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वीं भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥*

**Shiva Samhitayam (Excerpted from Gita Press Gorakhpur Veda Katha Issue, page. 285).:**

> *वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
> रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥*

**Brahma Samhitayam (quoted from the Upasana Trayasiddhanta, page. 55).:**

> *वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
> रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥*

The meaning of the above three shlokas are the same as that of the Bhavishya Purana's shloka. Which is as follows.:

> ***"O Goddess (Parvati), in the Age of Kali, Valmiki will be re-born as Tulsidas. He will again write the story of Rama Chandra into a virtuous language."***

Again, Shri Vaishnav Acharya Shrimad Goswami Nabhadas Ji Maharaj, the author of **Bhaktamal,** has also written the same about Tulsidas Ji in his book (1585).

> *"कलि कुटिल जीव निस्तार हित वाल्मीक तुलसी भयो"*
>
> ***(Iti Bhaktamal, 126 chappayi, page 131, Maluk Peeth edition)***

> ***"Valmiki ji incarnated in the form of Tulsidas ji to take the creature of Kalyug across the Worldly Ocean."***

> *सर्वलोकोपकाराय प्रेरितो हरिणामुदा।
> वाल्मीकिस्तुलसोस्दासस्तद् रूपेण भविष्यति।।
> **(Shri Brihad Brahma Ramayana- Q.1 Shloka.078).***

> ***Meaning- Shri Valmiki Maharshi will appear in the form of Shri Tulsidas ji by the will of Shri Hari for the benefit of all people.***

> *भाषा काव्यं मानसाख्यं रामायरणमनुत्तमम् ।*
>
> *करिष्यति जनानां यत्कलौ शीघ्र फलप्रदः ॥*
>
> ***(Shri Brihad Brahma Ra 0 Pr 0 1 Shloka 0 79).***

> ***Meaning- Shri Goswami ji will make the best language poem famous by the name Shrimanas Ramayana, which will give quick results to all the people in Kaliyuga.***

**Srimad Ramcharitmanas Mahatam described in Brihad Brahma Ramayana.:**

> *श्रीयाज्ञवल्क्य उवाच~*
> *५) वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासो भविष्यति कलौ युगे ।
> शिवेनात्र कृतो ग्रन्थः पार्वतीं प्रतिबोधितम् ॥*

> ***Meaning:~ 5) Shri yagyavalkya ji said that in Kaliyuga, Shri Valmiki ji will incarnate in the form of Goswami Tulsidasji, this Shri Goswami Tulsidasji, will write the book that Shivji has created to impart knowledge to Parvati, the Shri Ramcharit Manas.***

> *६)*
> *राम भक्ति प्रवाहार्थं भाषा काव्यं करिष्यति।
> रामायणं मानसाख्यं तत्ते शंकां निवारयेत् ॥*

> ***Meaning:~ 6) Through the same book, in order to make the juice of devotion to Shri Ram flow, that is, to increase it. Sri Tulsidas will create a poetry. That Ramayana known as Mānasa should dispel your doubts about it.***

At the same time, **the Sri Mahakala Samhita** also describes the fruits of reciting Srimad Ramacharitmanas.:

> *भव रोग हरी भक्तिः शक्ति यस्व शुभ प्रदा । ज्ञान वैराग्य सहितं कीलकं यस्य कीर्तिम् । तं मानसं राम रूपं रामायणमनुत्तमम् । प्रणमामि सदा भक्त्या शरणं च गतोस्म्यहं ॥ श्रीमदरामायणं दिव्यं मानसं भुक्ति मुक्तिदम् । यस्व श्रवण मात्रेण पापिनोऽपि दिवंगताः ॥*

**Translation.:**

> ***Dispelling maya (illusion) and disease, devotion to Hari bestows, power, fame and auspiciousness. Knowledge, along with renunciation, is the key to his fame. O Rama that mental (manasa/Ram Charit Manasa) form is the supreme Ramayana. I always bow down to you with devotion and take shelter of you.  The Śrīmad-Rāmayāna is a divine Manasa book that gives enjoyment and liberation to even sinners after they die just by hearing about you.***
>
> ***(Iti MahaKala Samhita).***

Comment: Excellent answer as always sir!  Just one genuine suggestion..If u could also add english translations of the verses it would help other people here who don't know Samskruta Hindi and Avadhi.

Comment: Yes, but translating all this in English is sure a headache, as i m not so good at translation

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stackexchange! While we do allow verses to be shared in the language written, but it is a must to add English translation for the same as the visitors of the site may not be knowing the languages other than English, Please edit and flag back for undeletion.