# What is the story of Badarayana Vyasa?

Tags: history, rishi, vyasa, ashwatthama

We know that present Vyasa is Krishna Dwaipayana. There is a detail about him in Mahabharata. But who is Badarayana Vyasa and what is his story? In which mahayuga was he the Vyasa?

Comment: [Related not duplicate] [Who all were the different Ved-Vyas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3617/3500)

Comment: Vyasa is for a Mahayuga or Chaturyuga and is changed after that a Mahayuga is one complete cycle of 4 yugas. Kalpa is really very big period. One kalpa contiains 1000 mahayugas so there would be 1000 Vyasas for each kalpa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Among_the_Devas

Comment: Badarayana is the same as Krishna Dvaipayana Vedavyasa.

Comment: @SreeCharan It's mentioned in the Vishnu Purana; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2390/36

Comment: Can anyone give reference vyasa badarayana

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Read this answer. [Why is it believed Brahma Sutras were written by Rishi Ved Vyasa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26386/5212)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Badarayana and Veda Vyasa are one and the same.The reason why Vyasa came to be known by the Badarayana name is explained in the following passage:

> In the Brahmasutra, on which there are commentaries according to the
>   various philosophical schools, Vyasa presents in an extremely terse
>   form the substance of the ten (principal) Upanisads. **Since he dwelt
>   under the badari tree (jujube) he came to be called "Badarayana" and
>   his work became well-known as "Badarayana-sutra".**

Source-[The BrahmaSutra on Kamakoti.org(part of Sri Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi's speeches)](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part5/chap31.htm)