# Why is it believed Brahma Sutras were written by Rishi Ved Vyasa?

Tags: scripture, brahma-sutras, vyasa

Brahma Sutras is a very famous text and the main text in the Vedanta tradition and it is believed they were written by Rishi Ved Vyasa, but there are points which say they were not written by Rishi Ved Vyasa.

However, the author mentioned in the Brahma Sutras is 'Badarayana'.

The Brahma Sutras mention Buddhism and Jainism where as Sage vyasa lived long ago when Buddhism and Jainism were nonexistent.

It has some verses which are considered written against Agamas, but Sage Vyasa Himself praised agamas in Mahabharata, the Linga Purana, Shiva Purana which are all written by Vyasa too also praises Agamas. Even many rituals mentioned in Shaivite Puranas are Agamic.

**So how can people claim and why is it believed  Brahma Sutras were written by Sage Rishi Ved Vyasa?**

Comment: Jainism is actually very old religion, they also belive in long timelines, as for Buddhism, the philosophy of Buddhism is very old Buddha just gave it his own interpretation.

Comment: @Anubhav Jha yes jainism is considered own but the tag of religion  Buddhism was invented by Buddha and in bs they are talking about buddha s buddhism and even yoga school is mentioned in that.Btw Jainism and Buddhism as a separate religion is not mentioned in other Hindu scriptures Rather then Brahma sutras.

Comment: Mahavira and buddha were contemporary in terms of time they lived. So how come it exist during the time of vyasa ? Was vyasa then lived post Buddhist era ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Jainism has been there before mahavira.

Comment: @AnubhavJha thats what they say but its not true. Islam say it was there before Mohammad and so on

Comment: @RakeshJoshi there are literally tirthankars before mahavira.

Comment: @AnubhavJha what is the reference ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi It is accepted by most historians that Parshvanatha, the 23rd Tirthankara and the Tirthankara before Mahavira did exist. Also, many have agreed his teachings are similar to Mahavira indicating Jainism existed before Mahavira. Another point is the first tirthankara who the Jain tradition considers the founder of the religion is mentioned in the Puranas as an incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: Badarayana and Krishna Dwaipayana are one and the same. [What is the story of Badarayana Vyasa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11749/5212)

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury but does this mean that Jainism existed pre vyasa era ? Buddha is avatar of vishnu tirthankar also avatar of vishnu... Whats going on ?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda See my answer .. it clearly shows that Veda Vyasa composed the Vedanta Darshana sutras or the Brahma Sutras. So, Badarayana is Vyasa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Kanchi Paramacharya (Chandrashekarendra Saraswati)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) too, Veda Vyasa and Badarayana are the same person.

He mentions about this in [this chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part5/chap31.htm) of the book called "Hindu Dharma", which is comprised of his various speeches/talks.

> In the Brahmasutra, on which there are commentaries according to the
>   various philosophical schools, Vyasa presents in an extremely terse
>   form the substance of the ten (principal) Upanisads. **Since he dwelt
>   under the badari tree (jujube) he came to be called "Badarayana" and
>   his work became well-known as "Badarayana-sutra".** Who or what is man
>   (the individual self)?

And, besides that, the Devi Bhagavatam explicitly mentions Veda Vyasa as the author of the Vedanta Darshana Sutras (which is another name for the Brahma Sutras).

> Seeing this distressed and sorrowful state of his father, S'ûkdeva,
>   with eyes full of wonder, said :-- Oh! What a power has Mâyâ got? Oh!
>   **He, whose words are accepted by all, with great love and care as
>   equivalent to the Vedas, who is the author of the Vedânta Dars'ana,**
>   and before whom nothing is veiled in ignorance, Oh! that greatest
>   Pundit, the knower of all the Tattvas, is now deluded by Mâyâ? Oh!
>   **what is that Mâyâ who has been able to delude Vyâsa Deva**, the son of
>   Satyavati, so skilled in the knowledge of Brahmâ Vidyâ; I also do not
>   know how, with what great care, one is to practise Sâdhanâ towards
>   Her. **Alas! He who has composed eighteen Mahâ Purânas and the great
>   Mahâ Bhârata, who has divided the Vedas in four parts, the same Veda
>   Vyâs has today been deluded by the power of Mâyâ!** What to speak of
>   other persons!
>
> [**From the Devi Bhagavata Purana's Book 1 ;Chapter 15**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam3-4.htm)

So, here Veda Vyasa is mentioned as the person who was deluded by Maya. He is mentioned as the author of Vedanta Darshana as well as the author of the 18 Puranas, the Mahabharata and also as the person who has divided the Vedas.

Therefore, this also shows that Badarayana is in fact Veda Vyasa.

Comment: So can that verse criticizing agamas can be interpolation?

Comment: No why? It is not criticising Agamic rituals or Yogic practices.. It has just said that it is not agreeing with what are mentioned as the efficient and material causes of the universe in certain Agamas (like Pancharatra etc) and Yoga Sutras .. that's all.. also all Darshana Shastras are equally authoritative.. so one refuting others do not have any value.. IMO it is the most Tamsik darshana because it is the latest among all of them and more because it is spending more time in refuting others than building it's own theory. Sankhya etc are ancient Darshanas. @KarmanyaNanda

Answer (score 8):

The possible explanation of your question is provided by author of the book [**Vedanta-Darshan**](https://archive.org/stream/HindiBookVedantDarshanBrahmasutraByGitaPress/Hindi%20Book-%20Vedant%20Darshan%20%28Brahmasutra%29%20by%20Gita%20Press#page/n5/mode/2up) (Brahma Sutra) **Harikrishna Das Goyandaka by  Gita Press.**

In his introduction of the book , the author is precisely talking about your question and the doubts regarding this matter. According to the author ,there is no problem in believing that the brahma sutras were authored by Ved -Vyasa whoes other name is also Badarayana. Below is the english translation of the explanation from the book.

> Herewith i would like to discuss some explanatory things regarding
>   Brahma-Sutras.This is  (Brahma-Sutras) is very ancient text. Some
>   scholars think that its a fairly  new one , by looking at the
>   criticism  of Samkhya , Vaisheshika ,Buddha, Jaina , Pashupata and
>   Pancharatra. And do think that Badrayana is different from Ved-Vyasa.
>   But this is their false notion. The philosophies which are criticized
>   in Brahma-Sutras are the eternal opinions /philosophies/views  are
>   eternal which are in flow i.e. those views are timeless . The great
>   debate between SadVada and AsatVada(Astika and Nastika) is going on
>   since from the ancient Vedic time itself. The Sutrakara not mentioned
>   the Acharyas of these philosophies anywhere in his work. He only
>   reviewed  "PradhanKaranVada(Samkhya) , AnukaranVada( vaisheshika) ,
>   VigyanVada etc.  The word Badrayana is associated with Ved-Vyasa since
>   long and used to mention one person only.  Panini also mentioned the
>   name of the text Bikshu-Sutras by son of the Parashara called Vyasa

Key Points -

1. Samkhya , Vaisheshika ,Boudha, Jaina , Pashupata and Pancharatra were eternal thoughts /views. They later formed their respective schools , but initially they were views only , before they got their seprate exsistance.
2. Bikshu-Sutras was the one of the name of Brahma-Sutras  written by Ved-Vyasa (son of parashara muni) ,which is mentioned by Panini .
3. Ved-Vyasa OR Badarayana only reviewed these thought /view systems and not the religions or philosophical schools.

This proves that Brahma sutras were written By Sage Rishi Ved Vyasa , whoes another name is Badarayana. And they both are same. And Buddhism and Jainism etc. mentioned /criticized were views /thoughts ,which are present from the beginning i.e. Astika VS Nastika.

---

Here is the [**screenshot**](https://cdn.exoticindia.com/books/gpa048e.jpg) of the above introduction in Hindi.

---

In Puranas also Shree Ved-Vyasa is called as a Badrayana. For example  Shreemad Bhagvat Purana calling Rishi Ved-Vyasa as Badaryana in the following Shloka.

> यानि वेदविदां श्रेष्ठो **भगवान् बादरायण:** ।
>  अन्ये च मुनय: सूत
>   परावरविदो विदु: ॥ [**SB 1.1.7**](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n15/mode/2up) ॥
>
> yāni veda-vidāḿ śreṣṭho **bhagavān bādarāyaṇaḥ**
>  anye ca
>   munayaḥ sūta parāvara-vido viduḥ
>
> O suta ! Whatever the venerable Badrayana greatest among the learned
>   ones ,knows and whatever other sages who knows saguna and nirguna
>   brahman.

Now see  the footnote clearing declaring Ved-Vyasa the author of Brahma Sutras is same as Badrayana.  see p.19.

---

[image]

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda - Updated the answer with verse confirming Badrayana ad Ved-Vyasa are the same person ,who wrote Brahma-Sutras.

Comment: Ok,but why would he crictizise agamas?since he praised them in Mahabharata and even Shiva puran written by him is quite based on Tanra rituals.

Comment: How is that verse proving that Badarayana and Veda Vyasa are the same? @SwiftPushkar