# What is the significance of the curse given by Sri Krishna to Ashwattama?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, krishna, kalki, ashwatthama

Ashwattama who was Dronacharya's son was Lord Shiva's Ansh(part)  himself.After the Kurukshetra war, Ashwattama avenged his father's death by killing Drishtidyumna and five sons of Pandavas when they were asleep. After that when He was confronted by Pandavas, He along with Arjuna used Brahmastra on each other.

After Sri Krishna,Vyasa and Narada's intervention both Arjuna and Ashwattama agreed to take back their weapons. However,while Arjuna was able to take his Astra back, Drona never taught Ashwattama about taking BrahmAstra back. So, Sri Krishna asked Aswattama to direct His Astra to some other direction. Ashwattama in his anger directed the astra to Uttara's womb. SRI Krishna saved Uttara's son(Parishcit).

Krishna then cursed Ashwatthama that he will roam in the forests with blood and pus oozing out of his injuries and cry for death till the end of Kaliyuga. Some say this curse also made him immortal while other say he was Chiranjivi from birth.

So my question is, why did Sri Krishna cursed Aswattama. Even Kamsa killed Krishna's brothers when they were born and all the babies in Gokul.Even after this Sri Krishna gave Kamsa an easy way by killing kamsa Himself thus ultimately giving him moksha. Similarly even Ganga killed her seven babies before Bhisma. Duryodhana and Dushasana insulted Draupadi but even their punishment was not as extreme as Ashwattama. Also given the fact that Aswattama was part of Lord Shiva Himself and that He will be Vyasa in next Manuvantara, why Did Sri Krishna cursed him with such extreme punishment? Is there any significance to it? Will Ashwattama,like Lord ParshuRama have some role in Kalki Avatara?

Comment: foeticide is bigger crime than killing children. he was brahmin also so may be mratyudanda was not suitable for him as it would incur Brahmhtya papa to opponents.

Comment: @Lakhi How is foeticide a biggier crime than killing all new born babies in a town? Even if it is, Ashwattama was Shiva avatar..I also read somewhere that he prayed to Shiva before doing this deed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ashvatthaman's immortality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2388/ashvatthamans-immortality)

Comment: @sv. I have already seen this question. My question is about the curse itself and not about immortality of Ashwattama.

Comment: Read the final line in the other question, "Any insights on the why of all this?" and then compare with your title here. Also, see the final line in the top-voted answer: "So presumably it is the time that Ashwatthama will have spent with Vyasa, engaging in spiritual pursuits and atoning for his sins, that will make him deserve to succeed Vyasa."

Comment: @sv. Well my question is about Krishna's reason of cursing like my question gives example of Kamsa and others. I know Aswattama is immortal and he will be next Vyasa

Comment: Even with your examples, your title question here has the same meaning as the other.

Comment: 'Similarly even Ganga killed her seven babies before Bhisma' - this had nothing to do with Krishna so not sure of its relevance here. Your main question (why Did Sri Krishna cursed him with such extreme punishment? Is there any significance to it?) has been sufficiently answered in the other question.